# BLE UART how to read RX

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, adafruit

I'm trying to send data from adafruit RF8001 to Android via BLE using UART service, the RX characteristics.getProperties() == 16, that means it can notify instead of readCharacteristics()...then how can I get information through the notification? Thanks

Comment: Call `setCharacteristicNotification` instead of `readCharacteristic`... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: thanks, but how can I get the string information sent via BLE? I just got notified that which characteristic changed..

Comment: Can you post some of your relevant code so I can see what you are doing? So you have an update receiver that lets you know a notification has come in? Then you just get the characteristic from the notification and extract the data it has (which is your string). The link I posted shows an example of this.

Comment: If you already have the characteristic from receiving the notification, then you can just call `characteristic.getStringValue(0);` to get the string.